# Django, change username

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to change the username?

I tried the following :-

```
user = User.objects.get(username = username)
user.username = newusername
user.save()
```

Nothing changes

I can change the username in the admin screen, but there are more than 100 where the client asked for different usernames to be used.

Comment: Have you checked if you get a result back? Though you would have some sort of error for that. Put your `user = User.objects.get(username=username)` inside a try-catch with an exception `User.DoesNotExist`

Comment: I think the code will work, so strange.

Comment: What do you mean, "nothing changes"? That code will work assuming your `User` model has a `username` field.

Comment: Do you intend to change the username of the usertype that comes along with django? Like superuser etc?

Comment: Argh!!! I missed the () on the save - sorry guys, one of those idiot moments for me. Thank for your patience. It works now.

Comment: @jimscafe Can you post a reply to your question and accept the answer

Comment: see this answer, it worked for me: [Change username for authenticated user in django User model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18590102/15128298)

Answer (score 17):

As you note ([Django, change username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355183/django-change-username/17664467#comment19963848_14355183)), this was a mistake in your code - the code sample did not reflect your code. The code sample posted will in fact work to change a `User` object's username:

```
user = User.objects.get(username = username)
user.username = newusername
user.save()
```

Comment: jimscafe already wrote that their sample worked, so this answer did not add much. That is presumably why you were downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

There is one more possible scenario why username does not change after save...

Your username in User object has default max length of 30 and you try to change the username to something longer than 30 chars and the first 30 chars of new and old username are the same ;)

Answer (score 2):

Before changing the username, also make sure the username does not already exist:

```
if User.objects.filter(username=newusername).exists():
    raise forms.ValidationError(u'Username "%s" is not available.' % newusername)

user = User.objects.get(username = username)
user.username = newusername
user.save()
```

Comment: If the user exist but the user is the user changing username? I would also verify whether the existing user is not the same user that change his username