# Change username for authenticated user in django User model

Tags: django, authentication

After authentification with social auth plugin, plugin create new user with not beauty usernames like sergey.kostin.345, I know that some users has a nice shorturls on the social media platforms and its ok for default behavior but I want to give user ability to change user names. As far as I understand django auth system does not let me to change User.username field by using methods. I also tried to change this field by using this code, but it seems to be ignoring in django.

```
owner = User.objects.get (id=request.user.id)
owner.username = newusername
owner.save()
```

owner is authenticated user

Comment: I'm sure this code will work. Are you getting any error?

Comment: it looks like nothing is happens. Maybe I need to logout right before change username and login again after changes?

Answer (score 3):

That would work, but there's no need to get the user again. `request.user` is already the user object.

```
owner = request.user
owner.username = newusername
owner.save()
```

Comment: Daniel should i logout and login again after I change the value of username?